# Load XML files from a folder with Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to load XML files from a specific folder with Pyspark. But I don't want to use **com.databricks.spark.xml** package. From every example, I get using com.databricks.spark.xml package.

Is there any way to read XML files without this package?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use 'xml.etree.ElementTree as ET'? If yes, then write a function in python using this function, and create a udf. Read the XML files into PySpark as RDDs and parse them with the udf.